# Negative margin Issues only with IE

Tags: html, css

I'm having a issue with the navigation bar drop down positioning in IE.

As you can see, the `Adhesive Tapes` drop down is positioned fine on hover but when hovering over '`Adhesives`' and `Sealants` it is slightly out of position.

I've checked it in Firefox and it's the same but only out by a few pixels.

I've spent some time this morning trying to solve it but only have limited knowledge.

Any help would be great.

[www.stickyproducts.co.uk](http://www.stickyproducts.co.uk)

HTML:http://pastebin.com/z7tu6wCX

CSS:http://pastebin.com/XjnXqEN8

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I understand you are new here. Next time trim the code. I was able to run it in my IDE at work but some folks here get irritated with long code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't set the position of the drop down menu to -999. I would position it in the exact spot it needs to be and then set the `visibility:` property to `hidden;`

something like this

```
.dropdown_4columns_sealants {

margin:4px auto;
float:left;
position:absolute;
left:-999em; /* I would set this to position where it should be all the time */
text-align:left;
padding:10px 5px 0px 5px;
border:1px solid #777777;
border-top:none;
z-index: 999;

visibility: hidden; /* I would set this to hide the menu right where it is at */
```

}

then in my JavaScript I would change the `visibility` property to visible when you hover over the links rather than reposition it from the original `-999em`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a problem with the dropdown, unless there is something else I'm not seeing. But I did see you are forcing a margin -9px to left. I corrected that. Here is the code corrections and the before and after pictures

```
 #menu, .nav-cush {
     margin: 0px;
 }

.overhang-right {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
}
```

You can actually replace those margin corrections in the css that is already made for them instead of copying and pasting that exact code I gave you. That way you don't have to use !important to overrride anything.

Since you are displaying several behaviors in different browsers. I've edited the lines below with browser hacks. I tested in all browsers and they work. Please do some testing yourself and let me know if it needs work or mark it as an answer so that others can benefit from it.

Find and replace the following:

```
.dropdown_4columns_adhesives {
     width: 988px;
     float: left; 
     margin: 11px 0 0 -204px; /* Chrome & Safari */
     margin: 11px 0 0 -198px \0/IE9; /* IE9+ & Opera*/
 }
 @-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .dropdown_4columns_adhesives {margin: 11px 0 0 -203px;} /* Firefox */
 }
 .dropdown_4columns_sealants {
     width: 988px;
     margin: 11px 0 0 -349px; /* Chrome & Safari */
     margin: 11px 0 0 -339px \0/IE9; /* IE9+ & Opera*/
 }
 @-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .dropdown_4columns_sealants {margin: 11px 0 0 -348px;}/* Firefox */
 }
```

This shows your menu bar pushed to the left
[image]

This shows your menu bar and ad image corrected

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry if i have been unclear. Here is the issues i'm talking about..The adhesive tape is working correctly http://files.stickyproducts.co.uk/images/tapes.jpg http://files.stickyproducts.co.uk/images/adhesives.jpg http://files.stickyproducts.co.uk/images/sealants.jpg

Comment: If it answered your question you should mark it answered so that other visitors can use it as well

Comment: did you make the changes I suggested? Refer to my image with the corrected changes and you'll see the adhesives dropdown also fixed. Is there a particular browser that is giving you problems?

Comment: Yes I made the changes but with no success. The .overhang-right & .overhang-left are for my sidebars so they hang over the edge of the main content area. I tested the code you provided just to double check but unfortunately it didn't work. In regards to a particular browser, it is IE that is causing me problems, as you can see in the screenshots the drop down alignment is out on 'adhesives' & 'sealants'. In firefox this is only by 1px or 2px which i can live with.

Comment: You shouldn't have to "live with" it. Front end development is for meticulous people. On that note, I didn't test it in IE because I run IE11 in my laptop which is pretty good with modern web standards, but I'll take a look at it in my work office where I can run all versions of IE

Comment: If it answered your question you should mark it answered so that other visitors can use it as well

Answer (score -1):

A better way to handle what you're doing would be to absolute position the dropdown within the main `ul#menu` (set to relative). Also, take position:relative OFF of the `#menu li`

this way you could set the dropdown div to `position:absolute; top:100%; left:0; right:0;` .

The way you have it right now (handling with negative margin) is dependent on the browsers' font rendering. As you can tell this is not consistent between browsers.

Doing it this way you wouldn't have to specify anything for the individual submenus. `top:100%; left:0; right:0;` would be able to be used for all 3.

An alternative option would be to set specific widths on all of your top level menu links.